# flutter_login signup additional password field has different backgroung color

Tags: flutter

I am developing a mobile application, for the login I am using flutter_login. I wanted to change the background of the signin box, which I could, but when I want to sign up and the additional confirm password field appears, it has a different background.
Here is how it looks like: [Login screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28E6h.jpg)

Here is my login:

```
child: FlutterLogin(
        title: 'GlobaLink',
        logo: const AssetImage('images/welcome_page.png'),
        onLogin: (data) => _authUser(data, context),
        onSignup: (data) => _signupUser(data, context),
        onSubmitAnimationCompleted: () {
          Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => const HomeScreen(),
          ));
        },
        onRecoverPassword: (name) => _recoverPassword(name, context),


        theme: LoginTheme(
          primaryColor: Colors.lightBlue[700], 
          accentColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent, 
          errorColor: Colors.redAccent, 
          pageColorLight: Colors.lightBlue[50],
          pageColorDark: Colors.blueGrey[900],
          titleStyle: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.blue.shade900,
            fontFamily: 'Quicksand',
            letterSpacing: 2,
          ),
          // TextField style
          textFieldStyle: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.blueGrey.shade800,
            shadows: [Shadow(color: Colors.blue.shade100, blurRadius: 2)],
          ),
          // Button Theme
          buttonTheme: LoginButtonTheme(
            backgroundColor: Colors.blue.shade800,
            highlightColor: Colors.blue.shade600,
            splashColor: Colors.blue.shade400,
            elevation: 5.0,
            highlightElevation: 4.0,
          ),
          // Input Theme
          inputTheme: InputDecorationTheme(
            border: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue.shade800), 
            ),
            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue.shade500),
            ),
            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue.shade700),
            ),
            labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue[800]), // Dark blue for label text
            errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.redAccent), // Red color for error border
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

I tried to change the color back to white but the color still remains lighter. Also there is an issue where the default colors of the login appear sometimes, mostly at circular loading signs. I looked through the whole project and there are no purple colors anywhere.